# Outlook 2010 ribbon button to change font possible?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is it possible to add a button to the Outlook 2010 ribbon that will change the font of highlighted text to "Courier New" and reduce the font size to 10 point? Not the whole document, just the highlighted text.

Having to click twice on Font and twice on Font Size to do this is aggravating to my carpal tunnel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a macro will work, but requires enabling macros which Outlook will warn about.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx shows how to enable maros, create a macro, and add it to the ribbon.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624331/vba-macro-to-highlight-selected-text-in-current-email-message has code in the answer which will perform changes to the currently selected text.

To change the Font to courier new, 10 point, bold, black I am using this macro derived from the second link:

```
Sub ChangeSelectedFontToCode()
 Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector

 Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector

 If insp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
     Set msg = insp.CurrentItem

     If insp.EditorType = olEditorHTML Then ' outlook 2003
         Set hed = msg.GetInspector.HTMLEditor
         Set rng = hed.Selection.createRange
         rng.pasteHTML "<b><font style='color: black; font-size: 10pt; font-family:Courier New;'>" & rng.Text & "</font></b>"
     End If

     If insp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then ' outlook 2013
         Set hed = msg.GetInspector.WordEditor
         Set appWord = hed.Application
         Set rng = appWord.Selection
         rng.Font.Size = 10
         rng.Font.Color = wdColorBlack
         rng.Font.Bold = True
         rng.Font.Name = "Courier New"

         rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
     End If

 End If

 Set appWord = Nothing
 Set insp = Nothing
 Set rng = Nothing
 Set hed = Nothing
 Set msg = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: In the end, I finally just created a new custom "Style" and set a key to apply it to the text highlighted with the cursor. It cannot be set to a button in the ribbon, but it was easier to use while cutting and pasting the text I wanted shown with the alternate Style, because I was already using Ctrl-V to paste and so my hands were on the keyboard, not the mouse.